# Can someone help me fix this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.js, undefined

So I've made a discord bot that can read other bot embed and reply it

Here's my code:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
  let embed = message.embeds[0];
  if (
    message.author.id == "555955826880413696" &&
    embed &&
    embed.fields &&
    embed.fields[0].value.includes(
      "Type **CATCH** (once) to collect some coins! The reward depend on how much players join\n"
    )
  ) {
    message.channel
      .send(
        "<@&742328576237633546> " +
          "<a:coins:744946097558126662> " +
          "**CATCH** " +
          "<a:coins:744946097558126662>"
      )
      .catch(console.error);
  } else console.log(embed);
});
```

It worked nicely, but after sort of time it crashed and said:
[image: Error Message]

Comment: All this means is that there is no value in the first embed field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `embed.fields` requirement from the `if` statement to `embed.fields[0]`

The error is triggering because `embed.fields` is empty (although still defined).